# Пробел между сокращениями "ст.ст."

Tags: сокращения, пробелы

Нужен ли пробел между сокращениями "ст." в предложении: "На территории Республики Беларусь зарегистрировано 4119 дорожно-транспортных происшествий (ст.ст. 317-319, ст. 321 УК Республики Беларусь)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одно ***ст.*** следует убрать. Правильно: ***ст. 317–319***.

Из ответа на аналогичный вопрос **справочной службы Грамоты.ру:**

> **[Вопрос № 231326](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=231326)**
> …Поскажите, пожалуйста, верное употребление след. сокращений:
> <…>
> 2) ***ст.ст.*** или ***ст. ст.*** (с пробелом) - если мы говорим о
> нескольких статьях одного документа или закона. например,
> руководствуясь ***ст.ст. 167 - 170*** АПК
> РФ?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Правильно: гг., ***ст.,*** подп. Источники: «Русский орфографический
> словарь», «Справочник издателя и автора» А. Э. Мильчина, Л. К.
> Чельцовой.

**[Из Мильчина:](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html#id-4%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-434%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)**

> **4.3.6** <…> **Не меняют форму во мн. ч.:**
>
> 1. графические сокращения слов тома, листы, страницы, столбцы,
>    принятые в библиогр. описании и перешедшие в другие виды текста;
>    напр.: **т. 1-10,** 10 л. ил., 250 с, 1040 стб.;
> 2. **все неоднобуквенные графические сокращения с точкой на конце;** напр.: в табл. 10 и 11; на
>    рис. 85, 91 и 101; в Запорожской, Днепропетровской и Полтавской обл.